# Eclipse Neon 2 & JUnit 4: Class cannot be resolved

Tags: java, junit

I have a java class `GeneticAlgorithm` and a junit test class, `GeneticAlgorithmTest`. Defined on `GeneticAlgorithm` is a static method that I'm trying to test, `reproduce`. In my test case, I have a call to that static method `GeneticAlgorithm.reproduce`.

When I try to run the `JUnit 4` test runner in Eclipse, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
GeneticAlgorithm cannot be resolved
```

Eclipse isn't giving me any compile time errors and the `JUnit 4` test runner works if I remove that line.

How can I resolve this error? Any help is appreciated. I should mention that this is a `Maven` configured project.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I somehow managed to fix this by changing the configuring the build path order of my project. You can get there by right clicking on the project name, then go to `Build Path -> Configure Build Path`.

I moved my maven dependencies up above the jre system library. For some reason, that worked.